# How can I center my text?

Tags: html

No matter what I do, my links in text continue to align to the left. The CSS is:

```css
p {
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Gotham-Bold;
  src: url(Gotham-Bold.otf);
}
```

```html
<header>

  <h2> <img src="Links Link.png" text-align="center" width="207" height="106"></h2> 

</header>

<p> <a href="http://www.chicagotribune.com/entertainment/ct-talking-pictures-mpaa-ratings-20140828-column.html"> Click here to learn about the "Love Actually" controversy </a> 
</p>
<p> <a href=: "http://apecsec.org/mpaa-rating-system-controversy/"> Click here for more information on the MPAA rating system </a> 
</p>
<p> <a href="http://www.cnn.com/2012/03/08/showbiz/movies/bully-rating-controversy-ew/"> Click here to learn about the "Bully" controversy </a> 
</p>
<p> <a href="https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/investigate-chris-dodd-and-mpaa-bribery-after-he-publicly-admited-bribing-politicans-pass"> TAKE ACTION! Sign the petition here </a> 
</p>
```

Does anyone know what it is I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Don't think "Float:center" exists

Comment: What are you viewing this in? This produces the following view - http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/u4g7hfp3/

Comment: There is no `center` value for float...

Comment: Does this help: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html?  P.S. `float: center;` isn't valid CSS.

Comment: There is no `src` CSS property.

Comment: The center cannot hold.

Comment: It looks centered to me. What is your goal that is not being accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Nix the float:center; "center" don't exist as an attribute of float.

Then try this:

```
p {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Gotham-Bold;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/qpxjmprv/1/)

Comment: Just so you know, `p` is always `display: block;` so there's no need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the wanted behaviour with your code...

Where is your css positionned ? (which directory compared to the html)

Make sure to use it like this

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css"/>
</head>
```